# Docker network interface not released to host name space

Tags: linux, docker, networking, docker-network

We are running a docker container like this

```
docker run -d --network=none --name test -p 1642:4000 test .
```

After that , assigning a network interface to docker container from the host OS like this .

```
sudo pipework --direct-phys ens1f1.955 -i ens1f1.955 <container_id> dhclient-f U:ens1f1.955
```

After doing this , when we kill the container forcefully , if i run netstat -i on the host , the interface ens1f1.955 is not showing up . Can someone help ?

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with `pipework`, but if I'm reading that command correctly your host doesn't *have* an `ens1f1.955` interface.  It has a `ens1f1.942` interface.  You're naming it `ens1f1.955` inside the container, but when the container is destroyed so is that alias.

Comment: Hello , Sorry for the typo the only interface under consideration is ens1f1.955 . Updated the question

Comment: Can you update your question to include (a) the output of `docker ps` before running pipework, (b) the output of `ip link show` before running pipework, (c) the output of `ip link show` after running pipework (while the container is still running), (d) the output of `docker ps` after your container exits, and (e) the output of `ip link show` after the container exits.  Thanks!

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response . Found that the issue was because a dhclient process was holding onto the interface and hence wasn't getting released . Tried killing the dhclient process and do a network restart and everything was going well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the issue was because a dhclient process was holding onto the interface and hence wasn't getting released . Tried killing the dhclient process and do a network restart and everything was going well . Alternative to network restart is to do ifup